# Exchange web services emails with msg file attached

Tags: c#, email, exchangewebservices

Am processing emails using exchange web services. Is new to me but this works fine, however I've come across a 'feature' I can't resolve.

I have to save the emails to disk, so I do in the eml format using:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, email.MimeContent.Content);
```

Sometimes the emails I process have an msg file attached to them, but when I load the saved eml file, I see the msg attached is now in eml format as well.

How can I keep an msg attachment as an msg attachment when saving to an eml file?

Answer (score 0):

How are you setting the filename? Can you check the original attachment format/extension and then save the new one with the same extension?